# SplashScreen for Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have to do a splash screen effect for a project in Adobe AIR. Mainly, I want to show an image for 3 seconds and than show the menu. I tried this:

```
public var myInterval:uint;    
public function Main() { 
      myInterval = setInterval(start, 3000);
}
public function start():void {
      clearInterval(myInterval);
}
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2):

did you miss

```
myInterval.start();
```

by any chance

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `setInterval` if you're open to getting familiarized with a 3rd party library, [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) is my prefered tweening engine. You could also give your splash screen a nice fade out effect as well with something like:

```
import gs.TweenMax; 

TweenMax.to(splashScreenInstance_mc, 1, {alpha:0, onComplete:SplashScreenIsGone, delay:3} );

//Optionally start loading other stuff here 

function SplashScreenIsGone():void {
    //Do stuff after splash screen is gone, such as show your menu
}
```

The code basically waits 3 seconds then fades the `splashScreenInstance_mc` to alpha of zero over 1 second, then calls a function after it's done. Very useful for any splash screen implementation.

Comment: I would just use TweenLite if you are just tweening the alpha.

Comment: As Adam said, `TweenLite` would be sufficient enough in this case. Just replace `TweenMax` with `TweenLite` in the code and download the appropriate library if you want to go that route. Nice suggestion Adam.